# PHP/XPath: Iterating through ancestor nodes in XML using SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I need to loop through the `Ancestors` nodes in order to get corresponding `BrowseNodeId` and `Name` values. How do I do this using XPath? I'm trying something like the the following, but it's not working:

```
//BrowseNode[1]//Ancestors[1]/BrowseNode/BrowseNodeId/text()
//BrowseNode[1]//Ancestors[1]/BrowseNode/Name/text()
```

I think the `//Ancestors` part of the XPath is actually searching the entire XML tree. What I need to do is visit each node to get the needed values. How do I do this? In the example below, I want: Europe -> History -> Subjects -> Books.

Example XML:

```
    <BrowseNode>
        <BrowseNodeId>4952</BrowseNodeId>
        <Name>France</Name>
        <Ancestors>
            <BrowseNode>
                <BrowseNodeId>4935</BrowseNodeId>
                <Name>Europe</Name>
                <Ancestors>
                    <BrowseNode>
                        <BrowseNodeId>9</BrowseNodeId>
                        <Name>History</Name>
                        <Ancestors>
                            <BrowseNode>
                                <BrowseNodeId>1000</BrowseNodeId>
                                <Name>Subjects</Name>
                                <IsCategoryRoot>1</IsCategoryRoot>
                                <Ancestors>
                                    <BrowseNode>
                                        <BrowseNodeId>283155</BrowseNodeId>
                                        <Name>Books</Name>
                                    </BrowseNode>
                                </Ancestors>
                            </BrowseNode>
                        </Ancestors>
                    </BrowseNode>
                </Ancestors>
            </BrowseNode>
        </Ancestors>
    </BrowseNode>
```

Comment: @Alejandro 's answer is better than the one you have accepted. The accepted answer is in fact wrong, because doesnt obtain any node at all: the XPath expression `/Ancestors/BrowseNode` doesn't select any node because your XML document doesn't have a top element named `Ancestors`. Please, consider accepting a correct answer, because accepting a wrong answer may mislead other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$browse_nodes = $xml->BrowseNode;
foreach ($browse_nodes as $browse_node) {
    echo $browse_node->BrowseNodeId.nodeValue;
    echo $browse_node->Name.nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this works. The XML I have is huge, and has a lot of the top level `BrowseNode` elements. Also, I am only interested in the `Ancestors/BrowseNode` of each top level `BrowseNode` element. Meaning, I need something like this: `//BrowseNode[1]/Ancestors/BrowseNode`, then `//BrowseNode[2]/Ancestors/BrowseNode`, then `//BrowseNode[3]/Ancestors/BrowseNode` ... The problem is that the // is searching the entire tree, I think. What I need is to walk the sub-tree of each top level `BrowseNode`

Comment: oic, maybe try single slash xpath('/Ancestors/BrowseNode'), then xpath('/Ancestors/BrowseNode/Ancestors/BrowseNode'), etc.

Comment: probably don't need xpath for this. you cn iterate through a set of children like you would an array.

Answer (score 1):

> In the example below, I want: Europe
>   -> History -> Subjects -> Books.

I think you need:

```
//Ancestors/BrowseNode/Name
```

Or just iterate over `//Ancestors/BrowseNode` results and get the `Name` and `BrowseNodeId` children with any DOM method.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to locate the final node, then extract is ancestors ?

```
<?php

$xml = "
    <BrowseNode>
        <BrowseNodeId>4952</BrowseNodeId>
        <Name>France</Name>
        <Ancestors>
            <BrowseNode>
                <BrowseNodeId>4935</BrowseNodeId>
                <Name>Europe</Name>
                <Ancestors>
                    <BrowseNode>
                        <BrowseNodeId>9</BrowseNodeId>
                        <Name>History</Name>
                        <Ancestors>
                            <BrowseNode>
                                <BrowseNodeId>1000</BrowseNodeId>
                                <Name>Subjects</Name>
                                <IsCategoryRoot>1</IsCategoryRoot>
                                <Ancestors>
                                    <BrowseNode>
                                        <BrowseNodeId>283155</BrowseNodeId>
                                        <Name>Books</Name>
                                    </BrowseNode>
                                </Ancestors>
                            </BrowseNode>
                        </Ancestors>
                    </BrowseNode>
                </Ancestors>
            </BrowseNode>
        </Ancestors>
    </BrowseNode>
";


$sxe = simplexml_load_string($xml);

// Set the target to reach
$target = current($sxe->xpath("//BrowseNode[./BrowseNodeId = '283155']"));

// Get all names from root to target
$names = array_map('strval', $target->xpath('ancestor-or-self::Ancestors/BrowseNode/Name'));
print_r($names);
// Array
// (
//     [0] => Europe
//     [1] => History
//     [2] => Subjects
//     [3] => Books
// )

// Get all ids from root to target
$ids = array_map('strval', $target->xpath('ancestor-or-self::Ancestors/BrowseNode/BrowseNodeId'));
print_r($ids);
// Array
// (
//     [0] => 4935
//     [1] => 9
//     [2] => 1000
//     [3] => 283155
// )

// Final
$combined = array_combine($ids, $names);
print_r($combined);
// Array
// (
//     [4935] => Europe
//     [9] => History
//     [1000] => Subjects
//     [283155] => Books
// )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/BrowseNode/Ancestors//BrowseNode/Name/text()
```

Will work with you sample.

However, it will search all nodes descandant to the "first" `Ancestors` element. Reversing and looking from the deepest `BrowseNode` would do pretty much the same.

In XSLT the viable and necessary alternative would be using keys for better efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood your description of precisely what you want,  but hopefully not.  This snippet looks for all of the "top level" `BrowseNode` elements and loops over them, getting their associated ancestor `BrowseNode` elements each time.

```
// Get top level BrowseNode elements
$browse_nodes = $xml->xpath('//BrowseNodes/BrowseNode');
foreach ($browse_nodes as $browse_node) {
    // Get ancestor BrowseNode elements
    $ancestors = $browse_node->xpath('Ancestors//BrowseNode');
    // Do whatever you like with them! :-)
}
```